# Move object and follow it in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

Is there a way to, while moving an object in edit mode, move at same time the 3DView camera? I don't mean a camera as an object, I mean the view in 3DView, I use this a lot in Unreal Engine, while moving an object with gizmo while pressing Shift, you can move the object and camera at same time.